# After the StarCraft 2 beta is over will achievements earned carry into the retail version?

Tags: starcraft-2, achievements

I was lucky enough to accepted into the StarCraft 2 beta. I've earned a few achievements from normal game play. Some of the achievements are a bit harder to earn and will take effort. If those achievements aren't going to carry into the version being released on July 27th I won't bother. So is there information anywhere about whether or not achievements earned in the StarCraft 2 beta will carry into the retail version?

Comment: this question is too localised (limited to a certain point in time) in my opinion.

Comment: @alex, IMO, it may be useful as reference for future questions about games of the same company -- it will likely behave the same way.

Comment: I think a generic Community Wiki `[faq]` question is better suited for that.

Comment: I don't think this requires CW. Even though more information is gleaned about this. It's only gleaned once. Right now, there is a definitive answer. "No" It will always remain that.

Comment: The answer to "does stuff from beta carry over into the real game" is almost invariably "no". The point of beta is to catch bugs and exploits before they become an embarrassing problem in the release; people getting to play early is just a side effect.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All achievements will be wiped upon release. It's beta - meaning it's there for testing, not for boosting your achievements before the game is even released.

The only achievement (or Feat of Strength) you'll probably get is that your participated in beta.

Source: [Battle.net forums](http://forums.battle.net/thread.html?topicId=24401614785&sid=5000)

Comment: Verified. Achievements wiped.

Answer (score 2):

Blizzard wiped previous beta accounts in StarCraft 2 so I don't think that's going to happen.

Moreover, they never preserved WoW beta achievements or gave a WoW feat of strenght for being in a expansion beta.

Comment: +1 u don't think so to. They always have reseted the account completely before