# Will Diablo III beta achievements persist into the retail release?

Tags: achievements, diablo-iii

Has Blizzard mentioned anything about D3 beta achievements and rewards persisting into the retail release? Did they do that for the SC2 beta?

I'm digging it but with the prospect of losing my character progress (again -- it is a beta after all) and potentially achievements (again, again) my desire to load it up is waning.

Comment: They most likely will. I mean it's beta after all. You might get a feat for participating in beta, like with SC2: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2747/after-the-starcraft-2-beta-is-over-will-achievements-earned-carry-into-the-retai

Comment: They wiped and disabled them during one of the recent patches, which is what prompted this question.

Comment: I would put large sums of money on the answer being no.

Comment: Too localized now that the beta is done

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**No.**

Blizzard has now officially confirmed what everyone suspected.  See the first three posts at

http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/4081811796

> **Forum poster**: iam 100% sure there is nothing that will carry over from
>   beta same as Starcraft2 beta
>
> **Blizzard CM**: Correct. The Diablo III beta is a completely different
>   game in Battle.net from the retail game that is Diablo III.